# Marquee is showing on two lines instead of one - HTML & CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I've tried everything but... marquee is showing in two lines but i want it on one line.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Protected","Protected","Protected");// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM questions");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<style>";
        echo "marquee { white-space: pre; }";
        echo "</style>";
        echo "<marquee>";
        echo '<span class="name">' . '&#8226;' . "<b>Naam:</b> " . $row['naam'] . "<b> Vraag:</b> " .       $row['vraag'] . "</span>". "</marquee>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Does anyone know the problem in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code must be like this

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","Protected","Protected","Protected");// Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM questions");
    echo "<style>";
    echo "marquee { white-space: pre; }";
    echo "</style>";
    echo "<marquee>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


        echo '<span class="name">' . '&#8226;' . "<b>Naam:</b> " . $row['naam'] . "<b> Vraag:</b> " .       $row['vraag'] . "</span>";
    }
    echo "</marquee>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code out side of while loop, Reason its showing you twice cause, Your are returning two row from your query**

```
echo "<style>";
       echo "marquee { white-space: pre; }";
       echo "</style>";

       echo "<marquee>";
```

The last line `echo "</marquee>";` after the while loop, and rest of the line above while loop

Comment: I saw it, sorry, my bad. Thank you very much for your answer!